# How to define the vertical layer of the material I'm painting on?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using a `CustomPainter` to draw a reveal animation that ends up covering the whole screen. The problem is that there are still elements that seem to be above my painter and thus stay visible.

My widget looks like that:

```
Material(
  elevation: 10.0,
  type: MaterialType.circle,
  color: Colors.white,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: reveal,
    child: CustomPaint(
      painter: CircularRevealButtonPainter(context, _fraction, backgroundColor: Colors.white),
      child: child,
    ),
  ),
);
```

The `reveal` function starts animating `_fraction` which is used by the painter to increase the size of the circle until it covers the screen.

The visible element that is supposed to be painted over is at `elevation` `0.0`, so that property doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there another way I'm not aware of?

Comment: have you tried using the stack layout? https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Comment: There's no z-index in flutter.

Comment: @F-1: Nope, mainly because the widget is re-usable and shouldn't depend / be aware of its surrounding widgets.

Comment: @RémiRousselet: Look at it as a metaphor for "something where I can define on which vertical layer I'm painting on".

Comment: I know, but there's no such thing in flutter. They are painted in order from parents to children and top to bottom. There's no exception to this rule